# Passar vetor de tipo struct como parâmetro de uma função em C

Tags: c, struct

Preciso criar uma função que está em um arquivo .h que gere numeros aleatorios n (definido pelo usuario e passado por parametro na função), e preencha o conjunto b com os valore gerados.

arquivo tConj.cpp

```
TConj a,b,c,d;
    int elemento, i,op;
    long unsigned num;
    if (op==6){

    int num;
    printf("Quantidade de elementos a ser gerado: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    b = GerarConjunto(num);
}
```

arquivo TConj.h

```
struct TConj{
    int * elemento;
    int n;

};
TConj GerarConjunto(int n){

TConj vet;
vet.elemento = (int *) malloc(10*sizeof(int));
int var;    

for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
    srand(time(NULL));
    var = rand()%n;
    vet.elemento[i] = var;
}

return vet;
}
```

Comment: Para fazer uma pergunta é necessario dizer qual o problema que você está tendo, e o que já tentou fazer. Esperar que as pessoas tenham bola de cristal para saber o que você quer, ou o que está errado só olhando o seu programa não e de bom tom.

Comment: Achei estranha a tag C nessa pergunta, considerando que o seu programa tem extensão Cpp, além do fato de você estar falando sobre vetores.